# Formatting GHC core?

Tags: haskell, ghc, code-formatting

When running GHC with `-ddump-simpl`, I get `.dump-simpl` files which are formatted in a way that's pretty hard to read.

Example snippet:

```
            { (# ipv_aAYC, ipv1_aAYD #) ->
            (# ipv_aAYC
                `cast` ((GHC.Prim.State#
                            (Lamdu.Calc.Infer.R:WorldSTInfer[0]
                                <GHC.Prim.RealWorld>_N ; (Control.Monad.ST.Class.D:R:Worldt[0]
                                                            <ReaderT
                                                                (InferEnv
                                                                    (STVar GHC.Prim.RealWorld),
                                                                STRef
                                                                    GHC.Prim.RealWorld
                                                                    Lamdu.Calc.Infer.QVarGen)>_N
                                                            <MaybeT
                                                                (GHC.ST.ST
                                                                    GHC.Prim.RealWorld)>_N ; (Control.Monad.ST.Class.D:R:Worldt[0]
                                                                                                <MaybeT>_N
                                                                                                <GHC.ST.ST
                                                                                                    GHC.Prim.RealWorld>_N ; Control.Monad.ST.Class.D:R:WorldST[0]
                                                                                                                                (Nth:0
                                                                                                                                    (Nth:2
                                                                                                                                            (Nth:3
                                                                                                                                                (Nth:3
                                                                                                                                                    (<(InferEnv
                                                                                                                                                        (STVar
                                                                                                                                                            GHC.Prim.RealWorld),
                                                                                                                                                        STRef
                                                                                                                                                        GHC.Prim.RealWorld
                                                                                                                                                        Lamdu.Calc.Infer.QVarGen)>_R
                                                                                                                                                    ->_R Sym (GHC.ST.N:ST[0]
                                                                                                                                                                    <GHC.Prim.RealWorld>_N
                                                                                                                                                                    <Maybe
                                                                                                                                                                        (STVar
                                                                                                                                                                        (World
                                                                                                                                                                            (STInfer
                                                                                                                                                                                GHC.Prim.RealWorld))
                                                                                                                                                                        ('Knot
                                                                                                                                                                            T.Type))>_R) ; Sym (Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe.N:MaybeT[0]
                                                                                                                                                                                                    <GHC.ST.ST
                                                                                                                                                                                                        GHC.Prim.RealWorld>_R
                                                                                                                                                                                                    (Lamdu.Calc.Infer.D:R:UVarSTInfer[0]
                                                                                                                                                                                                        (Sym (Control.Monad.ST.Class.D:R:WorldST[0]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    <GHC.Prim.RealWorld>_N) ; (Sym (Control.Monad.ST.Class.D:R:Worldt[0]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        <MaybeT>_N
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        <GHC.ST.ST
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            GHC.Prim.RealWorld>_N) ; (Sym (Control.Monad.ST.Class.D:R:Worldt[0]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            <ReaderT
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                (InferEnv
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    (STVar
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        GHC.Prim.RealWorld),
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                STRef
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    GHC.Prim.RealWorld
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    Lamdu.Calc.Infer.QVarGen)>_N
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            <MaybeT
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                (GHC.ST.ST
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    GHC.Prim.RealWorld)>_N) ; Sym (Lamdu.Calc.Infer.R:WorldSTInfer[0]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        <GHC.Prim.RealWorld>_N)))) <'Knot
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    T.Type>_N))) ; (Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe.N:MaybeT[0]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        <GHC.ST.ST
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            GHC.Prim.RealWorld>_R
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        <Tree
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            (UVar
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                (STInfer
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                GHC.Prim.RealWorld))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            T.Type>_N ; GHC.ST.N:ST[0]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            <GHC.Prim.RealWorld>_N
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            <Maybe
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                (Tree
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                (UVar
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    (STInfer
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        GHC.Prim.RealWorld))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                T.Type)>_R)))))))))_R
                        :: GHC.Prim.State# (World (STInfer GHC.Prim.RealWorld))
                            ~R# GHC.Prim.State# GHC.Prim.RealWorld),
```

Where is the code? Mostly requires scrolling a lot to the right to see, and it is mostly type annotations with one word per line. Quite difficult to follow and I wonder if things could be better.

I tried using `hindent`, `brittany`, and `stylish-haskell` to format the file (it's basically a variant of Haskell, isn't it?) but none of those support it..

I also saw the [`ghc-core`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-core) tool which should produce readable output but I've failed to figure out how to use it in a stack-based project (it wraps the system GHC?).

Any advice for how to make the core more readable?

Comment: You might like [dump-core](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dump-core).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [these options](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/debugging.html#suppressing-unwanted-information). Specifically, you need `-dsuppress-coercions`, which should shrink that huge `` `cast` ... `` into something like `` `cast` <Co:5> ``.

Comment: Thanks! I've now used `-dsuppress-coercions -dsuppress-idinfo -dsuppress-module-prefixes -dppr-case-as-let -dppr-cols=1000` and the output is much more useful!